# Simple OLS regression and detrending

Tags: least-squares

If I was to only do a simple OLS regression, do I still need need to detrend my data at the first difference like I do for a VAR. Or can I simply use the data as it is.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. You would want to know if the variables in the regression are stationary, and if not, take differences until they are. OLS on non-stationary variables will generally be invalid.

I say 'generally' because it is actually only the error term that needs to be stationary, but usually the way to address the risk of non-stationary error terms is having stationary variables. Granted, you could have non-stationary variables and stationary error term in the case of cointegration, but if that's the technique you want to use you will need to be careful about how you do inference (since the parameter distributions don't follow normal OLS ones).

See for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_relationship

Comment: There is no requirement that the variables should be stationary. It is the error term that must be stationary.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - edited post accordingly

Comment: how would one make the error terms stationary. thank you for the answer by the way, to offer more contextI am using the log of gdp per capita as my dependent variables with oil price as my main independent along with other such as net exports and inflation to calculate the impact of oil price on a net exporting country. I am able to difference most of my variables and this should ensure a more accurate OLS model, yes?